# Why is my ImageView with alpha invisible when placed over opaque ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, transparency, opacity

In my Android app I would put one image with a certain transparency over a background with maximum opacity. To try this, I have tried to create a relative layout, with a background image view (to create the background, with full opacity, alpha = 1), and over this one an other image view, with low opacity value (alpha). And, in the same relative layout, also a text view with some indications.

Very strange! On my Android emulator, all works correctly. But in more than one real device, I see perfectly the background image view and the TextView but the second image view (the one with the image in low opacity) is completely invisible! Why? Thanks, I copy my code under.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/controlImageView">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/controlImageViewBack"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bck_main"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_img_control_background"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/controlImageViewPicture"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/ctrl_bck"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/controlImageViewBack"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_img_control_picture"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/controlMessageText" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_alignTop="@id/controlImageViewBack"
            android:textSize="@dimen/board_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
            android:textAlignment="center" android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/mod_control_nomessage"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! From logs:

> 05-01 12:46:12.288 24904-24904/com.mycompany.myapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (840x2524, max=2048x2048).

Very strange, but for the first time I have seen that in some graphic element it is impossible to insert too big images.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, weight and layoutOrientation don't have any effects on a Relative Layout !

The Code worked on my Nexus 5X !

What real device do you use ?

Comment: Thank for your quick answer! Samsung Galaxy Nexus, Android 4.3 (min version compatibile with the app 4.0). On this device, the background image view and the textview are visible, but not the picture image view (with low alpha value).

Comment: Maybe you should log the following values for the Image view after set Content view : Width / Height / Alpha Value

Comment: could you Show us the log os we can help you ?

Comment: Already done, and already solved. Please see my previous answer. Thank!